# C++ - Comparing multiple int arrays and return array with smallest span

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a problem where i have multiple arrays that are to be compared against a single array. The array with the shortest span between indexes will be returned.

Here is an example of a set of arrays i would be working with:

(if it is of any importance these values represent RGB values)

```
int[] workingset = {55, 34,102};
int[] test1 = {54,36,99};`   
int[] test2 = {21,65,231};    
int[] test3 = {76,35,1};    
int[] test4 = {133,22,3};
```

Because `test1[]` values are closest to `workingset[]`, `test1[]` would be the array that would be returned.

*I apologize for not putting up sample code, but i simply could not think of a way to piece this puzzle together.

Comment: Do you mean comparing the arrays with your reference array cell by cell and choose the one that has the lowest overall stray ? In that case you should choose a distance function, too.

Comment: No, sadly, it has to find the shortest span average between all of the array's indexes.

Comment: What is the question? How to return arrays? How to calculate the "shortest span average"? How to select an array from a selection of arrays based on a distance function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily sum up all components (r,g,b) and check which has the smallest difference.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    int workingset [] = {55, 34,102};
    int test1 [] = {54,36,99};  
    int test2 []= {21,65,231};    
    int test3 [] = {76,35,1};    
    int test4 [] = {133,22,3};


    int sums [4] = {};
    for(int i=0; i<3;++i){
        sums[0] += abs(test1[i]-workingset[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "diff test1 " << sums[0] << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<3;++i){
        sums[1] += abs(test2[i]-workingset[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "diff test2 " << sums[1] << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<3;++i){
        sums[2] += abs(test3[i]-workingset[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "diff test3 " << sums[2] << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<3;++i){
        sums[3] += abs(test4[i]-workingset[i]);
    }   
    std::cout << "diff test4 " << sums[3] << std::endl;

    int smallestIndex = 0;
    int smallestDiff = INT_MAX;
    for(int i=0; i< 4; i++){
        if(sums[i] < smallestDiff){
            smallestIndex = i;
            smallestDiff = sums[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "array with smallest index: " << smallestIndex << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I edited the microsoft specific includes and datatypes.

Comment: What is `#include "stdafx.h"`? What is `_tmain`? What is `_TCHAR`? You should not give a Microsoft-specific answer to a non-Microsoft-specific question.

Comment: these are just the default imports of visual studio. you could just replace it by whatever is needed. As he does not ask for a specific environment I just came up with my own standard stuff. However, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i just gave your code a run, works just as expected! cheers!

Comment: the answer from @bobah has the same effect. the square and abs function have the same intention.

Answer (score 0):

What's your metric for "shortest span between indexes"?  I'm guessing that you're trying to minimize the sum of the absolute values of the differences between the two arrays?

Once you've defined your metric, try something like this pseudocode:

```
min_metric = MAX_INT
min_array = null
for array in arrays:
    if array.length() == workingset.length():
        metric = calculateMetric(workingset, array)
        if metric < min_metric:
            min_metric = metric
            min_array = array
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess too. Assuming you are trying to write a color matcher. Consider these arrays vectors. Then the absolute length of the vector difference between `workingset` and `testX` will be the metric to use.

Or in the code:

```
int [] delta = { 0, 0, 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < delta.length; ++i) delta[i] = workingset[i] - testX[i];
double metric = 0;
for (int x: delta) metric += x * x;
metric = sqrt(metric); // and use this to assess how far away the testX color is from the workingset color (sqrt operation is optional)
```

Comment: that sounds like a great approach, i will try this is the morning, do you know if this method is more or less accurate than @StevenB's answer? And could you please use an example?